# How to achieve this result using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the input below, what's the regex expression that gives the desired output in javascript? I must achieve this without using a multiline flag.

input

```
\n
\n
abc def.\n
\n
*\n
\n
```

desired output (maintain same number of rows but insert `=` into blank rows)

```
=\n
=\n
abc def.\n
=\n
*\n
=\n
```

actual output (using regex `/[^a-zA-Z0-9.*]+\n/` replaced with `=\n`; it somehow removes one of two consecutive `\n`s)

```
=\n
abc def.=\n
*=\n
```

Comment: Can you use a replacement function or does it have to be a static string?

Comment: I can use a replacement function

Comment: Don't you mean insert `=` into blank rows?

Comment: Yes, corrected. thanks.

Comment: I couldn’t find a single non-multiline regex replacement for this either. Here is a [**regex101 snippet**](https://regex101.com/r/9j8NAH/1/) with your example input, to help others test their attempts in the browser. The closest I got was searching for `[\s\S](?=\n)` and replacing with `=$0`, but it still doesn’t work. I was attempting to use positive lookahead `(?=)` to not consume the next line so it could be matched too.

Comment: @JasonO. Please check out my answer and see if it works :)

Comment: I discovered a very odd javascript regex interaction thanks to this question... For some reason, `'\n'.match(/(^(?=\n))?/)` returns `["", undefined]` instead of `["", ""]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a combination of replace functions like so:

```js
str = "\n\nabc def.\n\n*\n\n";

str = str.replace(/\n/g, "=\n");

str = str.replace(/(.)=\n/g, "$1\n");

console.log(str);
```

## Explanation -

After the first replacement/s, the output looks like:

```
=
=
abc def.=
=
*=
=
```

Then, you replace any characters followed by a `=\n` and replace it with **that same character** (given by `$1`), followed by a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired outcome is *"maintain same number of rows but insert `=` into blank rows"*.

An empty (*"blank"*) row is a row that matches the `regex`: `^$`.

`^` means the beginning of the input string, `$` means the end of the input string but if the `m` modifier is specified (it means *"multi-line"*), `^` matches the beginning of a line and `$` matches the end of a line.

Your code should be as simple as:

```
input = "\n\nabc def.\n\n*\n\n";

output = str.replace(/^$/mg, '=');
```

The `m` modifier changes the meaning of `^` and `$` as explained above. The newline characters are not matched by the `regex` above and consequently they do not need to be present in the replacement string.

The `g` modifier tells [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to find and replace all the matching substrings, not only the first one (the default behaviour of `String.replace()`).

Read more about [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with two `replace` :

`value.replace(/^\n/, '=\n').replace(/\n\n/g, '\n=\n')`

- The first `replace` takes care of the first line if it starts with a blank row.
- The second `replace` takes care of other lines : adding `=` in blank rows is the same than inserting `=` between two consecutives `\n`